What is an efficient way to create the list [0, 2, 3, ..., 234] in python?
I want to create the list [0, 2, 3, ..., 234] in python, possibly within a row and without listing all numbers explicitly
I know that following code works:
list1 = [0]
for i in range(2,235):
    list1.append(i)

But are there any possibilities to finish that within a row?

You can literally write [0, 2, 3, ..., 234], that's valid Python :-)

Another efficient way, combining simplicity and performance, is to use unpacking:
list1 = [0, *range(2, 235)]


I would suggest that this be accepted as the correct answer rather than mine (though I agree with @nocomment about overloading the keyword), since it's not only a one-liner per the OP but empirically performs better than mine.

list1 = [0] + list(range(2,235))

list will expand a lazy enumerator.

This is probably not as efficient as the other two answers but is a direct translation of your code to a 1 liner.
list1 = [0] + [i for i in range(2,235)]
